# Redux Toolkit: How can I store a serialized action creator in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

## Question

I am using Redux Toolkit and I want to store an action creator in state. When I do this, I receive an error regarding non-serializable values in my action as well as my state. Using the code below as an example of my issue, how can I resolve it without just suppressing the warning?

## Slice Code

```
import { ActionCreatorWithoutPayload } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export type ModalType =
  {
    type: 'MyModal';
    actionText: string;
    onConfirm: ActionCreatorWithoutPayload;
  }

type ui = {
  modal: ModalType | null;
};

const initialState: ui = {
  modal: null
};

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'ui',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    showDialog: (state, action: PayloadAction<ModalType>) => {
      state.modal= action.payload;
    },
    someAction: (state) => {
      // do something
    },
  }
});
```

## Component Code

```
import { someAction } from 'reducers/uiSlice';

<Button
  onClick={() =>
  dispatch(
    showDialog({
      type: 'MyModal', actionText: `Some text`, onConfirm: someAction}
    )
  )}
/>
```

## Error Message

```
A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the state: `payload.onConfirm`. Value: ƒ actionCreator() {
    var args = [];

    for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
      args[_i] = arguments[_i];
    }

    if (prepareAction) {
      var prepared = prepareAction.apply(void…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this is a bad idea, and really not at all how Redux should be used.

Based on the examples, it *looks* like you're trying to create a modal and pass in a callback as a prop.  There are other ways to do this that will work better with Redux, and in fact a few years ago I wrote a post on [Managing Modals and Context Menus with Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-10-managing-modals/).  It shows a few different techniques to do this in a way that is compatible with how Redux should be used.

Today, the option I'd recommend is using a custom middleware that tracks what modals are open, returns a promise from `dispatch(showModal())`, and resolves the promise when you do `dispatch(closeModal(modalId))`.

The post links to https://github.com/AKolodeev/redux-promising-modals as one option for this.  I also have an incomplete but mostly working similar implementation in a gist at https://gist.github.com/markerikson/8cd881db21a7d2a2011de9e317007580 that shows some of the potential approaches.

Comment: Is there a way that I can pass a Redux-Toolkit ActionCreator as a serializable action-to-be-dispatched?

Comment: @RouteMapper : no, and that's why I pointed you to alternate approaches that _will_ work.

Comment: Gotcha, I need an example of how to do all that using type safety in TypeScript.

Comment: You'll have to piece that together a bit :) The blog post I linked is plain JS (I wrote it in 2017). The `promising-modals` lib is JS. The gist I linked is a bit incomplete, but _is_ in TS, and is probably your best starting point. Sadly, I no longer have access to the final version of the production code I made after working on that gist, but if you have issues, come by the `#redux` channel in the Reactiflux Discord ( https://reactiflux.com ) and ask, and we can help get it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the SerializableCheck like below

```
import {getDefaultMiddleware} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const customMiddleWare = getDefaultMiddleware({
  serializableCheck: false,
});

export default configureStore({
reducer: {
...your reducers
},
 middleware: customMiddleWare,
});
```

Comment: This only suppresses the warning but does not fix the root cause of the error.